# Why doesn't useEffect directly support async callbacks or have separate parameters for the cleanup function?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I know I can't directly pass an async callback like this to useEffect

```
  useEffect(async () => { // not supported, as this implicitly returns a Promise
    const result = await axios(
      'https://someurl',
    );
 
    setData(result.data);
  });
```

as React expects nothing or a (cleanup) function callback as the first parameter for `useEffect`.

What I don't understand though: Is there any specific reason for this design choice? Why isn't there instead a signature like `useEffect(callback, cleanup, dependencies)` which would then allow me to directly pass in an async callback as first parameter, as the cleanup function could be easily passed in as second parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I don't understand though: Is there any specific reason for this
> design choice?

One of the reasons that comes to mind is following. In react often when you return function from `useEffect` it does job like unsubscribing from things etc. and often you might need to access some variables from `useEffect`. For example:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    let cancelled = false;
    fakeFetch(person).then(data => {
        if (!cancelled) {
            setData(data);
        }
    });

    return () => {

        cancelled = true;

    }

 }, [person])
```

With your design, you wouldn't be able to do above.

Comment: that sounds very reasonable, thank you :-)